# Ansible : MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to install AWS CloudWatch agent in EC2 Centos VM using ansible-playbook. It worked well in the sandbox but when I ran it in Production it fails (integrated with Jenkins pipeline)

Here is my task snippet:

```
      - name: setup temp directory for install
        file:
          path: /tmp/aws-cw-agent
          state: directory

      - name: download installer
        get_url:
          url: "{{ aws_cw_agent_url }}"
          dest: /tmp/aws-cw-agent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm

      - name: install agent
        become: true
        shell: rpm -U /tmp/aws-cw-agent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
```

Until "download installer" it works fine and I could find the rpm binary by manually navigating to the directory. But the next task install agent fails. Instead of shell, if I use "yum" module also, it fails.

The error says:

```
17:16:07 task path: /home/jenkins/workspace/groupesiph-dsir/03227/03227_Cloudwatch_Agent_deploy_hprod/playbook/deployment/roles/aws_cw_agent/tasks/main.yml:22

>17:16:07 Tuesday 10 March 2020  17:16:07 +0100 (0:00:00.098)       0:00:05.352 ********* 
17:16:08 Using module file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/commands/command.py
17:16:08 Pipelining is enabled.
17:16:08 <10.45.1.136> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible

>17:16:08 <10.45.1.136> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=10 -o ControlPath=/home/jenkins/.ansible/cp/84b84369b7 10.45.1.136 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-syqwibhfpdecwpfqddhe ; /usr/bin/python'"'"'"'' && sleep 0'"'"''

>17:16:08 Escalation succeeded
17:16:08 <10.45.1.136> (1, b'', b'')
17:16:08 <10.45.1.136> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: 
17:16:08 fatal: [prod05]: FAILED! => {
17:16:08     "changed": false,
17:16:08     "module_stderr": "",
17:16:08     "module_stdout": "",
17:16:08     "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
17:16:08     "rc": 1
17:16:08
```

But if it is a real problem with ssh, then how it is succeeding in the previous task to download the installer.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those two tasks (the `get_url` and `shell`) differ in that one has `become` and the other not -- so I would guess that your `sshpass` is misconfigured; you can run ansible in debug mode as `env ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 ansible -vvvv` and it will emit all kinds of helpful debug messaging, including why the module _really_ failed

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to debug.

Comment: post an answer to your own question, acknowledge @mdaniel and explain how you fixed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was user did not have sudoers access to install binary which using yum to install "/tmp/aws-cw-agent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm". With debug message I found the error.

Answer (score 0):

I would try again, but use the yum module instead..
something like this.

```
- name: install nginx rpm from a local file
  yum:
   name: /tmp/aws-cw-agent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
  state: present
  become: yes
```

Comment: I tried something as well before posting it, but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Hello only as informative I passed this same error and in the end I found that the problem was because in the `/etc/sudoers` file the user was configured as `user ALL-NOPASSWD:/bin/su`